# Can't get custom content type page template to load

Tags: theming

I'm running Drupal 7, and working with the Zen theme. I'm pretty sure I created a child-theme of Zen. My file structure looks like sites/all/themes/mytheme, with the original zen being located in sites/all/themes/zen. Not sure if any of that matters.

Anyway, I've created a custom content type and now I'd like to style the page differently (not just the node, but the entire page).

I've copied my page.tpl.php file and renamed it page-mycustomcontenttypename.tpl.php. This file is located in the same directory as my page.tpl.php file, which is sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates.

I then added the following code to template.php, which is in my theme's root folder:

```
<?php
/**
* Add / modify variables before the page renders.
*/
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

// custom content type page template
  // Renders a new page template to the list of templates used if it exists
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    // This code looks for any page-custom_content_type.tpl.php page
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-'. str_replace('_', '-', $vars['node']->type);  
  }
}
```

I then clear my site cache, but the changes I make to the custom template don't show up.

There's about a million places I could make a misstep here, so I'm not sure where to start? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can also find more information [here](https://drupal.org/node/1089656).

Answer (score 2):

I'm totally an idiot. I tried this code previously but it didn't work, which is why I ended up with the code above (also didn't work).

I realized that in the code I tried the first time I failed to change the first line to my theme's name:

```
<?php
function thisshouldhavebeenmythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node_' . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
?>
```